# How to prevent the creation of a terraform resource unless using a module

Tags: terraform

I have a modules folder in which I defined a resource with a set of preconditions and some variables validation conditions, this is owned by a central team and can't be modified by other teams. I created one folder per team , and the idea is that they can create a module that implements the resource mentioned above. What I'm trying to achieve is to prevent these teams from creating the same resource (without implementing the resource in the modules folder), because they would bypass the conditions and the validation that I set in the parent folder. Is there a way to do so with Terraform ?
I want the teams to **only** use module to implement the resource and not be able to create it from scratch.
I didn't manage to find a way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform CLI/Core itself is not in a position to enforce this sort of policy, because if it's running on someone's own computer the operator can make it do whatever they want.

However, it's common to impose this sort of policy by first setting up an automation pipeline to run Terraform in a controlled environment, outside of any operator's direct control. There's some guidance on how to set that up in the guide [Running Terraform in Automation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/automation/automate-terraform).

Once you have Terraform running in an automation pipeline, you can set up the pipeline to run arbitrary policy-checking code between plan and apply. That code can both block applying configurations that don't meet policy and also, if you wish, optimize your workflow by automatically approving certain types of changes that are routine and so are reasonable to apply immediately without interactive approval.

When adding a policy checking step, the general pattern is:

1. `terraform plan -out=tfplan` to generate a plan and save it to a plan file.
2. `terraform show -json tfplan` to obtain [the JSON plan representation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/internals/json-format#plan-representation).
3. Run some software you've written that parses the JSON plan representation and signals failure if the plan doesn't match your policy rules.
4. Assuming that the previous step didn't fail the pipeline, once someone has approved the plan you can run `terraform apply tfplan` to apply it.

For step 3, one way to implement the rule requiring the use of your module would be to implement two different tests that must both be true:

1. In `configuration.root_module.module_calls` there should be a call whose `resolved_source` matches your required module.
2. In `planned_values` there should not be any planned resource instance whose `values` data matches what you are intending to block, *unless* that resource instance is inside the module call you found for the previous rule.

Comment: Thanks Martin, much appreciated. This is indeed for an automated pipeline where we're using a service principal. this was the way we were thinking about it but I wanted to explore if there's  a way to restrict the "source" field inside the "module" for example without having to add it in the check phase of the CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: Terraform typically just does what it's told and assumes that you'll use processes like code review or automated checks to ensure that the input source code is compliant with your local policy. What I described in my answer was a way to impose policy after the plan has been created, which gives the most information to make decisions on. However, if you can define your policy rules in a way that relies only on the static, provider-agnostic parts of the configuration then it might be better in your case to use an automated check as part of your code review process.

Comment: For static checks on the source code the pattern is a bit different because those checks will tend to need to happen before Terraform is running at all. The Terraform team offers [terraform-config-inspect](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-config-inspect) as a Go library and an associated wrapping tool to inspect a subset of the configuration statically outside of Terraform; the "module calls" part of the result should give enough information to restrict module source addresses.